# When are Unix directory permissions enforced

Tags: unix

Say I have a directory that only root can access:

```
 $ sudo -s
 $ mkdir ~/rootonly
 $ chmod 000 ~/rootonly
```

Inside that directory is one with global-everything permissions:

```
 $ cd ~/rootonly
 $ mkdir openforall
 $ chmod 777 openforall
```

No if I want to access that directory as a normal user, I seemingly can't (as I would expect):

```
 $ su me
 $ cd ~/rootonly/openforall/
 bash: cd: /home/me/rootonly/openforall: Permission denied
 $ touch ~/rootonly/openforall/foo
 touch: cannot touch `/home/me/rootonly/openforall/foo': Permission denied
```

However, if I first cd as root into the directory, and then su to the normal user user, it does work:

```
 $ sudo -s
 $ cd /home/me/rootonly/openforall
 $ su www-data
 $ touch test
 $ ls
 $ -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 2011-08-05 14:17 test
```

Why does this work? Is the first case just a specific behavior of "cd", which tries to go through the directory hierarchy folder by folder? In other words, for an attacker bypassing the bash, does the kernel provide an entry to access "openforall" if the path is known?

I'm interested what is going on behind the scenes here.

Answer (score 1):

The permisions are enforced when a command needs to "traverse" a directory.

When you `touch ~/rootonly/openforall/foo`, the touch command needs to open the `rootonly` directory so that it can find the location (inode etc) of `openforall` so that it can then edit the contents of the `openforall` directory structure to set the timestamp there of `foo`.

Comment: So, it is not possible then to open a file directly solely with knowledge of it's inode?  Why does it work when using su? Is there some kind of directory file handle inherited to the child process? That does't seem right; AFAIK file handles are not generally inherited.

Comment: 1. See `man open`. 2. If you break the operation into stages and have different effective user ids for each stage, the permissions apply per stage. Files can be opened using relative paths that do not require reading of parent directories. 3. No, only cwd. 4. Correct.